# (Flutter) How to use Consumer and ChangeNotifierProvider correctly ? can't find what is missing

Tags: flutter, provider, consumer, changenotifier

This is the code (Fidev design challenge) step by step copied from source but got an error
classes in suspicion are MainPage and LeopardPage
have imported all necessary packages
Can't figure out what is missing

```
class LeopardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
    return Consumer<PageOffsetNotifier>(

        builder:(context,value,child)
    {
      return Positioned(
        top: 100,
        left: -0.85 * value.offset,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context.watch()).size.width*1.6,
        child: child,
      );
    },child: IgnorePointer(child: Image.asset('assets/leopard.png')),
    );
  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

To force the `Consumer` to use the `ChangeNotifier` you should *provide* it before, i.e.

```dart
class LeopardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => PageOffsetNotifier(), // lazy creation of model
      child: Consumer<PageOffsetNotifier>(
        builder:(context, value, child) {
          return Positioned(
            top: 100,
            left: -0.85 * value.offset,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context.watch()).size.width*1.6,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: IgnorePointer(
          child: Image.asset('assets/leopard.png')
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main Class is

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider(

      create: (_) {return PageOffsetNotifier(_pageController); },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[

            PageView(
              controller: _pageController,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              children: <Widget>[
                //LeopardPage(),
                VultturePage(),
              ],
            ),
            LeopardPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```